# Product images are serving from different paths on Product detail page and in sitemap

Tags: image, magento, sitemap

Product images are serving from different paths in view page & in sitemap.

1) product view page : `media/catalog/product/W/i/image-name.jpg` : [link1](http://totaltoys.com/media/catalog/product/W/i/Wishkey-Combat-Gun-With-Flashing-Lights-Sound-2.jpg)

2) http://sitename.com/media/sitemap.xml : `media/product/ee7/image-name.jpg` : [link2](http://totaltoys.com/media/product/ee7/wishkey-combat-gun-with-flashing-lights-sound-d1d.jpg)

but i want product images should serve from same path in both links:

**media.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image"
        src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'), true); ?>" />
    </li>


    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />



                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />


            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For delivering images in the frontend you should always use this call `<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage()); ?>` as it utilizes the Magento cache, if enabled.

Definately not default Magento is this path **media/product**/ee7/image-name.jpg - all product media related stuff is in **media/catalog/product**. It might be that you have an extension that uses *media/product* to store and server images - but this is not default Magento.
Please check your extensions, especially how the links in the sitemap are created.

Comment: `Catalog > Google sitemap` > there you can see url below  : `Link for google` i found the sitemap url there.
is that default magento url right ? but i have no idea why its generating  from that path.