# Change the path of product images path in magento site

Tags: magento

In product view page page, images are serving from this path :  [link1](http://totaltoys.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/chhota-bheem-himalayan-adventure-bow-arrow-_-sword-set.jpg)

`media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/image-name.jpg`  :

but I want to serve from this path :   [link2](http://totaltoys.com/media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/h197daf6fdf8885bc92bb6b117576f33d.jpg)

```
`media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/image-name.jpg` :
```

**media.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'), true); ?>" />
    </li>
    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />
                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />
            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product images are serving from different paths on Product detail page and in sitemap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185755/product-images-are-serving-from-different-paths-on-product-detail-page-and-in-si)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to copy app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php to **app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php**.

Then take a look to the file you just copied, l.313-319 :

```
    // build new filename (most important params)
    $path = array(
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath(),
        'cache',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        $path[] = $this->getDestinationSubdir()
    );
```

This "$path" array will build your catalog image path. Change it to whatever you like. In your case :

```
    // build new filename (most important params)
    $path = array(
        Mage::getBaseDir('media'),
        'cache/images',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        $path[] = $this->getDestinationSubdir()
    );
```

Dont forget to modify clear cache path too, l.686 :

```
public function clearCache()
{
    $directory = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.'cache'.DS;
```

... to ...

```
public function clearCache()
{
    $directory = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS.'cache'.DS.'images'.DS;
```

Next, go to your **media.phtml** file. Change :

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>
...
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>
```

... to ...

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')); ?>
...
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, sorry for delay, we are using an extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html , now i set image size using backend , so i am getting the path i required, but images are displaying in very big size in site [here](http://test.collagekingapp.com/baby-ball-large.html)

Comment: You can add a "resize" parameter like this : `<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()))->resize(300,300); ?>` where first argument is width, and second is height.